# Is it possible to fake your GPS location on windows phone?

Tags: location-services

I am using Nokia Lumia with Windows Phone OS. I want to change my GPS location so that it displays a fake location in one of my apps. Is it possible?
 From what I read, it's possible for Android only but not on Windows phone.

Comment: What do you mean by fake a fake location? Just don't use the actual GPS value, or modify it before use.

Comment: Why do you want to fake your location? Could you just not allow the application to use your location?

Answer (score 4):

This is currently not possible on Windows Phone due to the API restrictions that apps have to comply with.

In case you're the developer you can install the app on the Windows Phone Emulator and set your gps Location there.